# Android Studio Install SDK Error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

i try to Update version 5.0 layout Library inside android studio , but end of download return this error :

```
 Loading SDK information...
 Refresh Sources:
 Fetched Add-ons List successfully
 Refresh Sources

 Installing Archives:
 Preparing to install archives
 Installing SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
 Failed to rename directory E:\Android\SDK\platforms\android-21 to      
 :\Android\SDK\temp\PlatformPackage.old01.

 SDK Manager: failed to install
 -= Warning ! =-
 A folder failed to be moved. On Windows this typically means that a program      
 is using that folder (for example Windows Explorer or your anti-virus software.)
 Please momentarily deactivate your anti-virus software or close any running programs that may be accessing the directory 'E:\Android\SDK\platforms\android-21'.
 When ready, press YES to try again.
 Note: you  can use --force to override to yes.
 [y/n] =>

   Done. Nothing was installed.
```

[image]

then i try to input **`y`** character , disable Antivirus and check internet connection , but not resolve problem!

what is solution!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

Finally i resolve it!

1. Closing all Programs that related and Used `SDK` folder.(For ensure , disabling Antivirus, even AVD , Genymotion and... )
2. This path : Menu ---> File ---> invalidate Caches/Restart
3. try again for download - But this time just unzip downloaded package(it not download again)

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions

1. Set "No Proxy"

Seems to be a bug.

I went to Preferences -> HTTP Proxy Set the option to "No Proxy" from "Auto-detect proxy settings"

2. Run As Administrator
   start the android studio as administrator. that helps you in android studio whenever updates/installations are failed.

Comment: i used VPN for all connection and it not have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your E:\Android path installed the Android Studio? SDK can not in the Android Studio Path

Comment: No - `E:\Android` is my android tools folder in pc